# Is "eloquii mystici" a correct translation of "sorcerers/enchanters"?

Tags: vocabulary, translation-check

Is "Omnus nos eloquii mystici" correctly written to say "We are all sorcerers/enchanters"? I know there are different ways to say sorcerer or enchanter, but I really want to use "eloquii mystici". I just don't know if it's written correctly in plural.

Answer (score 3):

Almost!

*Omnus* is probably a typo: you want *omnēs* to mean "all". *Nōs* is the correct word for "us".

Now, *ēloquiī* literally means "of eloquence" or "of an utterance", while *mysticī* is an adjective meaning "mystical" or "relevant to secret rites". So the sentence currently means something like "we are all [the people] of mystical eloquence". A bit of a strange phrasing, but not incorrect.

Since you mention "in plural", however, I'm guessing these words don't actually mean quite what you think they mean—as it is, they're singular in your motto. If you clarify your intended meaning a bit, I might be able to help you more. (For a word for "sorcerers" or "enchanters", I would use the straightforward *magī* or the Greek-derived *goētēs*; most of the other Latin words for sorcerers are pretty negative, meaning things like "curse-maker".)

Comment: Exactly! Latin words for sorcerers are pretty negative and I read somewhere that "eloquii mystici" translated to something like expert magician, but I just wasn't sure about it. So "Omnēs nōs magī" is probably the best way to translate "we are all magicians/sorcerers"? Thank you for your time and help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @ValeVanilla If I were going from scratch, I'd actually say _omnēs magī sumus_. That just feels a bit better to me. But the meaning is the same.

Comment: You could also read *mystici* as a substantivized adjective, meaning "mysticians" instead of "mystical". Then the plurality is legitimate, meaning something like "eloquent mysticians".

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Wouldn't that require _eloquii_ to be an adjective though? I only know it as a noun.

Comment: I read it as "mysticians of eloquence", so that the genitive noun would have no attribute. Such genitives do tend to come with attributes, but I was just proposing a possible alternative.